# ROS Answers SE migration: rviz camera

Tags: rviz, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I need help. Can you tell me how to visualize the camera image on rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10170/rviz-camera/) by [snoworld](https://answers.ros.org/users/268/snoworld/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you will have to add a display to show images.
after you have done so it should show an interface where you can select the topic.
after selecting the right topic it should show a window, in which your image should be shown.
the link provide by lakshmen contains a clear explanation how to do this.

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at this. http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide  You need to add a [Camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Camera) display.

---

Originally posted by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) with karma: 101 on 2011-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3